# Prove that $P(X<a)=\lim_{x_{n}\to a}F(x_n)=F(a^{-})$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

> Prove that $P(X<a)=\lim_{x_{n}\to a^-}F(x_n)=F(a^{-})$

So I want to use this property if $A_1\subset A_2\subset...$ and $\cup_{k=1}^\infty A_k=A$ then $\lim_{k\to\infty}P(A_k)\to P(A)$

So I have $x_n\to a$ from below, I can assume the sequence $x_n$ is monotone increasing since if not there exists a subsequence which is, thus $x_1<x_2<..$

Then define $A_k=\{\omega: X(\omega)<x_k\}$, which should give me these open intervals $(-\infty, x_1)\subset (-\infty, x_2)\subset...$

Then since I know that the $x_n$ terms converge to $a$, I know that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (-\infty,x_n)=(-\infty,a)$

So then $\lim_{k\to \infty} A_k=\{\omega : X(\omega)<a\}=(X<a):=A$

So using the property above, $\lim_{k\to\infty} P(A_k)\to P(A)=P(X<a)$

Can I then say that $\lim_{k\to\infty} P(A_k)=\lim_{x_n\to a^-} F(x_n)$?

The only problem I see is that $F(x)=P(X\leq x)$ And I defined my $A_k$ sets as $(X<x_k)$ so I don't think writing $P(A_k)=F(x_k)$ makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x_n)$ be an increasing sequence with $x_n \to a$. Define events $A_n = \{X_n \in (-\infty , x_n]\}$. Note that this is an increasing sequence of sets ($A_1 \subset A_2 \subset \ldots \,$), so using continuity from below, we get: $$P(X < a) = P\left(
\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \right) = \lim_{n\to \infty}P(A_n) =\lim_{n\to \infty}F(x_n) = \lim_{x_n \uparrow a} F(x_n) = F(a^-)  $$

as desired.